# Get posts for last working week in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, loop, get-posts, date-query

With the date_query in wordpress I was trying to get posts for the last working week (Monday to Friday)

I was using:

```
$base_array        = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'fields'            => 'ids',
    'post_type'         => 'cpt',
    'post_status'       => array('publish'),
    'date_query'        => array(
            'before'    => 'next Saturday',
            'after'     => 'last Monday'
    )
);

 $base = get_posts($base_array);
```

But today, a Thursday, returns these values:

> From 31/10/2016 to 28/10/2016

Which makes sense with the 'last' days but is there any way that I can get the last Monday to last Friday? Regardless on the day the WP_Query is queried.

Comment: hope it would be helpful for you  http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-date-query/

Comment: @KanonChowdhury see I tried "after 1 week ago" and "before today" but I kept getting empty results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, try the below code-

```
$base_array        = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'fields'            => 'ids',
    'post_type'         => 'cpt',
    'post_status'       => array('publish'),
    'date_query'        => array(
            'after'     => strtotime( 'previous week Monday' ),
            'before'    => strtotime( 'previous week Friday' )
    )
);

$base = get_posts($base_array);
```

I've not tested it. But I tested that below code returns the perfect date-

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime('previous week Monday'));
date('Y-m-d',strtotime('previous week Friday'));
```

It returns-

> 2016-10-24 and 2016-10-28

Comment: coming to my rescue again!